# Sentence pattern: participle + adjective + object?

Tags: grammar, verb-pattern

I got stuck, trying to figure out how common and natural is the following construction:

> *he said, cracking open a beer*

Is it also possible to use "he said, cracking a beer open"? Could anyone add some more examples of the same sentence pattern, just to be sure I recognize the subtleties?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: It's very common. I drove slow, holding up traffic. The brick sat there, propping open the door. Amazon was up 4% today, lifting the overall market a bit. Etc., etc.

Comment: thx for response! And what about kinda things like: "he said, cracking a beer open", "I drove slow, holding traffic up", they sound unnatural or they are simply ungrammatical?

Comment: Neither unnatural nor ungrammatical, but idiomatic and grammatical.

Comment: The latter comes close to the grammar problem of ending a sentence with a preposition. There's a famous story about that aspect, relating to William Churchill. https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/11/14/churchill-on-prepositions/

Comment: @EdwardBarnard thank  you, Edward, very nice story which I will remind myself of while cracking a beer open ))

Comment: Your example sentence is perfect and sounds terrific.  The alternative (*cracking a beer open*) is grammatically correct but doesn’t sound as natural to my ear.

Comment: @whiskeychief thank you!  Well, It hurts me to say it, but the initial phrase isn't mine -- I've been reading the Goldflinch by Donna Tartt, so I picked it up from there.